# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined content.js:1(anonymous function) content.js:1 Chrome extension error?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

This is my manifest.json file.

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "1",
    "description": "Test",
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "jquery.js",
            "content.js",
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": [
                "content.js",
                "jquery.js"
            ],
            "matches": [
                "http://www.roblox.com/*",
                "https://www.roblox.com/*",
                "http://web.roblox.com/*",
                "https://web.roblox.com/*"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ]
}
```

My jquery.js file is normal just like the other ones.

My background.js just tells me when the document is ready.

and This is my content.js file.

```
$.get("http://www.roblox.com/--item?id=16412796", function(data){
    console.log($(data).find(".notranslate")[0].innerText);
});
```

It gives me this error of course for some odd reason.
`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined content.js:1(anonymous function) content.js:1`
How would I fix it?

Comment: Make sure you're running your get request that when jQuery has loaded.

Answer (score 3):

Move jQuery to be first. Scripts are executed in the order listed.

```
        "js": [
            "jquery.js",
            "content.js"
        ]
```